# where to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in windows7 for php?

Tags: php, windows-7, payment-gateway

I was building cybersource payment gateway on my site.

But its not work .

When I run this on my site it show and error

Fatal error: Call to undefined function cybs_load_config()
Any body tell me the solution of this.

and also how can i set LLD_LIBRARY_PATH ?